# Unable to centre the fourth and fifth subfigure in 2nd row

Tags: graphics

I want to use 5 subfigures, three arranged in first row and two in second row, both rows need to be arranged centrally. But I am facing problem in second row, the two images are placed at each end but not towards centre. Any way to handle it?

```
\begin{figure*}[!htb]
\centering
\subfloat[Original Depth Image]{
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=4.0cm]{cat.png}
\label{fig:subfigure1}
}
\hfill
\subfloat[Plausibility Map]{
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=4.0cm]{cat.png}
\label{fig:subfigure2}
}
\hfill
\subfloat [Depth Image of Guided Filter]{
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=4.0cm]{cat.png}
\label{fig:subfigure3}
}
\vfill
\centering
\subfloat[Blending Map]{
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=4.0cm]{cat.png}
\label{fig:subfigure4}}
\hfill
\centering
\subfloat[Blended Output Depth Image]{
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=4.0cm]{cat.png}
\label{fig:subfigure5}}
\caption{Results for Combination1: Plausibility Method-2 and Blending}
\end{figure*}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just play some games with `\hfil` and `\hfill`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[!htb]
\centering
\subfloat[Original Depth Image]{
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=4.0cm]{cat.png}
\label{fig:subfigure1}
}
\hfill
\subfloat[Plausibility Map]{
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=4.0cm]{cat.png}
\label{fig:subfigure2}
}
\hfill
\subfloat [Depth Image of Guided Filter]{
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=4.0cm]{cat.png}
\label{fig:subfigure3}
}
\vfill
\centering
\hfill\hfill\subfloat[Blending Map]{
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=4.0cm]{cat.png}
\label{fig:subfigure4}}\hfill
\subfloat[Blended Output Depth Image]{
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=4.0cm]{cat.png}
\label{fig:subfigure5}}\hfill\hfill\hfil
\caption{Results for Combination1: Plausibility Method-2 and Blending}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You. It's working....  I had tried other stuff, might be a little patience and trial and error method could work out. Yow're genius.

Answer (score 2):

I've made some changes to your example:

- There's no need to repeat the `\centering`, one time is sufficient.
- Instead of relying on automatic breaking within the figure, I used an explicit empty line.
- Comment signs `%` at the end of lines prevent unwanted spaces in the document.
- To have consistent spacing in the figure, I used a `\hspace{.05\textwidth}` to produce the whitespace in the bottom row.

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[!htb]\centering
\subfloat[Original Depth Image]{%
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=4.0cm]{example-image}%
\label{fig:subfigure1}%
}%
\hfill
\subfloat[Plausibility Map]{%
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=4.0cm]{example-image}%
\label{fig:subfigure2}%
}
\hfill
\subfloat [Depth Image of Guided Filter]{%
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=4.0cm]{example-image}%
\label{fig:subfigure3}%
}

\subfloat[Blending Map]{%
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=4.0cm]{example-image}%
\label{fig:subfigure4}}%
\hspace{.05\textwidth}%
\subfloat[Blended Output Depth Image]{%
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=4.0cm]{example-image}%
\label{fig:subfigure5}}%
\caption{Results for Combination1: Plausibility Method-2 and Blending}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

## Result

[image: result]

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes beat me to it, but at least our solutions aren't 100% equal.